# Foreach loop in PHP - looping through an array of results, displaying them in a single table row in HTML?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of orders that I am querying for totals, and I want to display them all by quarter. Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT shipping_number, SUM(qty) AS qty, SUM(cost) AS cost, 
QUARTER( TIME ) AS quarter
FROM order_items
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY quarter, shipping_number
ORDER BY quarter, shipping_number
```

And I have a simple table row in which I want to display these results in:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo '<th colspan="2" style="text-align: right !important; ">TOTAL QUEBEC - EASTERN CANADA</th>';
echo "<th>Amount<br />Quantity</th>";
foreach($results as $r) {
    if($r->shipping_number == "2326244" OR $r->shipping_number == "8451211"){
        if($r->quarter == "1"){ echo "<td>$r->cost $<br />$r->qty</td>"; } else { echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; }
        if($r->quarter == "2"){ echo "<td>$r->cost $<br />$r->qty</td>"; } else { echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; }
        if($r->quarter == "3"){ echo "<td>$r->cost $<br />$r->qty</td>"; } else { echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; }
        if($r->quarter == "4"){ echo "<td>$r->cost $<br />$r->qty</td>"; } else { echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; }
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Except that, obviously, the `foreach` loop goes through the results twice, resulting in not 4 cells being created but 8.

#### Sample results

[image: Results]

#### How the data is output right now

[image: Output]

#### Question

How do I output this on a single line, so that the data is either queried and formatted in a way that makes sense to run it only through one loop (or how do I output a single row of data from multiple loops?)

How would I do that?

Keep in mind, I have multiple shipping_numbers (clients) that might apply for a single table, so I need all of their totals combined in a single result, except separated by quarters (months, and so on - but those are separate queries).

Comment: The if block doesn't make too much sense, you should use  case switch.

Comment: why do you need the if statement in the loop?

Comment: Why don't you add the `shipping_number` to the query and limit it for the amount you want ? for example here 2 ..

Comment: umm, if I remove the IF from that loop and just print out each quarter's values, I either get half-empty table (if the output for quarters 3 and 4 doesn't exist those cells don't get written) and it ends up looking like this -> http://prntscr.com/73dh99 or if I'm printing out 12 months worth of data in 12 columns, and some of the months don't have any data, I'll get mismatched values printed out in wrong column for the wrong month (as the foreach loop would just print them out one after another, so I could get Jan, Mar, Dec printed out in Jan, Feb, Mar columns). Do you have a better way?

Comment: Could it be possible that you have two orders stored with the same shopping number? From your first example you have two orders, they both have identical shipping numbers but different attributes. Could the loop just be pulling two orders as it is pulling any order with that shipping number, and there are two of them? Thus the errors in the data, not in the loop code?

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this without rewriting the query:

```
$totals = array();
$totals["1"] = 0;
$totals["2"] = 0;
$totals["3"] = 0;
$totals["4"] = 0;
foreach($results as $result)
{
    if($result->shipping_number == "2326244" || $result->shipping_number == "8451211")
        $total[$result->quarter] += $result->cost;
}
foreach($totals as $total)
{
    echo "<td>".$total."</td>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change query to select each quarter is actually a decent option.

The if statements in this query are saying "if x quarter, then get the qty and cost separated by a new line, else 0."

```
SELECT
  IF(QUARTER(TIME) = 1, CONCAT(SUM(qty), '\n', SUM(COST)), 0) as q1,
  IF(QUARTER(TIME) = 2, CONCAT(SUM(qty), '\n', SUM(COST)), 0) as q2,
  IF(QUARTER(TIME) = 3, CONCAT(SUM(qty), '\n', SUM(COST)), 0) as q3,
  IF(QUARTER(TIME) = 4, CONCAT(SUM(qty), '\n', SUM(COST)), 0) as q4,
  shipping_number
FROM order_items
GROUP BY shipping_number, QUARTER(TIME)
ORDER BY shipping_number, QUARTER(TIME)
```

And then you'd have to change the echo lines to accomodate the query change. The `nl2br` function converts the `\n` from the query to a `<br>` like you have in your original post. It will just put a single 0 in the cell when the quarter had no results.

```
echo "<td>" . nl2br($r->q1) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . nl2br($r->q2) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . nl2br($r->q3) . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . nl2br($r->q4) . "</td>";
```

Comment: Just edited the answer to fix the echo statements. Wouldn't need the if statement for determining the quarters when you return all the quarters in the query. Also realized the Quarter is needed in the Group By, which I removed originally.

Comment: that still returns two elements in the array, meaning the foreach loop still runs twice, ending up in 8 rows being printed out instead of 4 - the same problem I had originally.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that something like this would work.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo '<th colspan="2" style="text-align: right !important; ">TOTAL QUEBEC - EASTERN CANADA</th>';
echo '<th>Amount<br />Quantity</th>';
$quarter = 1;
$it = 0;
$count = count($results);
$quarterPrinted = false;
while ($quarter <= 4) {
    for ($i = $it; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if ($results[$i]->quarter == $quarter
            && ($results[$i]->shipping_number == '2326244' || $results[$i]->shipping_number == '8451211')) {
            echo "<td>{$results[$i]->cost} $<br />{$results[$i]->qty}</td>";
            $it++;
            $quarterPrinted = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$quarterPrinted) {
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    }
    $quarter++;
    $quarterPrinted = false;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: same output that I had initially and the reason why I asked the questions -> http://prntscr.com/73w3j4 (back to square one)

Comment: @CrazySerb Maybe my edit will work better? I feel like I'm working for you now. :D